# Remove Header from Custom Template

Tags: php, css, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using a custom template named "full_width" which I downloaded from this tutorial/blog post: https://www.wpbasics.org/advanced-custom-fields-custom-front-page/
In this link you will find both, the php and css code.

Everything works fine but the fact that I cannot remove the main header (what I called Header "1" in the picture below).
[here you can see what I refer to when I write Header "1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTQgm.png)

I want to remove the Header 1 because I already have a second header (header 2 of the picture), which was already built in my website from my developer.

I thought was enough to replace the get_header() line at the end of the php code with the one which recalls my header "2". However it does not work.

At the moment, I changed the last part of the template code, by simply adding a new line (the second one) as follow:

```
get_header();

get_template_part('parts/header'); the_post();

do_action('full_width_content');

get_footer();
```

Obviously it will show the both headers. In fact, this is how the page currently looks like.

[image: This is how the page looks like if I keep the get_header() line]

If I delete the "get_header()" line, the layout of the page will turn like this (a mess)
[image: This is how the page looks like if I remove the get_header() line]

Can someone guide me to a solution. Let me clarify that I know nothing about coding, nor PHP, neither CSS. I am not a developer. Therefore I would need a ready to go solution which I simply need to copy and paste into my website.

Answer (score 0):

could it be as easy a

```
get_template_part('parts/header'); the_post();

do_action('full_width_content');

get_footer();
```

Comment: If I do as you suggested, the entire layout page will be ruined. My Hero section will not be shown properly, as any other image or text in the page.

I'll add to my initial question a couple of screenshots where you can see how the layout will change is I keep or remove the get_header() line

Comment: I guess the problem is with the style.css file.
If I remove the get_header() line, the stye.css file will not be properly called.

Comment: it's here: https://www.wpbasics.org/advanced-custom-fields-custom-front-page/

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code in the link above, adding simply get_template_part('parts/header'); the_post(); 
below get_header();

Comment: ACF is a plugin for wordpress, so you must have a wordpress installed somewhere? I need to see the code inside get_header(); aka the header.php file.

Comment: I found the problem. 
Somehow, the php code (the one here wpbasics.org/advanced-custom-fields-custom-front-page), needs to have the get_header() line to properly recall the CSS code in the style.css file (which is also in the same link:  wpbasics.org/advanced-custom-fields-custom-front-page).
If you do not put the get_header() line, the style.css file is not activated.

I found a solution. It's not a beautiful solution though. I just copied the code in the style.css file and pasted in the php code, just below the 
function do_full_width_content() {
In this way all works fine.